# Correct MVC pattern for User table

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I have a User model, with properties (id, username, email, password) and methods (is_unique, get_by_id, save).
As I understand the MVC pattern, my User model has to represent one given user.
So, if I want to get a list of all users, should I implement a method for this in User model, or in a controller?

Comment: Models should hold all interactions with the database.

Comment: According to @9miles said, You should implement Your `list of users` (accessing db) in model.

Comment: ...and what is wrong with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to build a UserCollection model, containing a collection of User models if you want to do it the proper MVC way. Your controller can never interact with the database directly, hence why we have to create a model ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should make a model class which represent a list of users, e.g. UserList.

Answer (score 1):

Neither of both.

Create a new Model called something like `userbase`or `clientbase` and use it to list users by criteria, retrieve information about your users in general (count, top 10, user of the month, etc...) and for operations that affect a group of users (that may have no direct relation one to another) like building a certain demographic collection of users to send them a mail.

Cheers